# How to skip empty cells in a range to use as range for a scatterplot?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and trying to dynamically select the data i need for my scatter plot. I'm trying skip any rows that have a blank in the "A" column so the scatter plot is continuous.

The code in the commented section is what i tried first, but that gives me a  method range of object_global failed error on the setsourcedata line. I expect the code to skip the empty cell and continue through mydatatest variable until it reaches the end. However, the actual output stops at the first empty cell.

```
Set mydatatest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data - PLC").Range("A3:A94")
'Set mydata = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data - PLC").Range("A2:C2")
Set mydata = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data - PLC").Range("A2")

For Each mydatapoint In mydatatest

    If IsEmpty(mydatapoint) = False Then
        'Set mydata = Union(mydata, Range(mydatapoint, mydatapoint.Offset(0, 2)))
        Set mydata = Union(mydata, mydatapoint)
    End If

Next mydatapoint

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Select
Set cht1 = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(10, 365, 275, 200)

With cht1.Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range(mydata, mydata.Offset(0, 2))
    '.SetSourceData Source:=Range(mydata)
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `.SetSourceData Source:=Range(mydata)`. It should be `.SetSourceData Source:=myData`. `myData` is already declared as `Range()`. The rest is quite ok:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myDataTest As Range
    Dim myData As Range

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    Set myDataTest = wks.Range("A3:A94")
    Set myData = wks.Range("A2")

    Dim myDataPoint As Range

    For Each myDataPoint In myDataTest
        If Not IsEmpty(myDataPoint) Then
            Set myData = Union(myData, myDataPoint)
        End If
    Next myDataPoint

    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = wks.ChartObjects.Add(10, 365, 275, 200)

    With cht.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=wks.Range(myData, myData.Offset(0, 2))
        .SetSourceData Source:=myData
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, declaring `Set myData = wks.Range("A2")`, just to have something to unite it - `Union(myData, myDataPoint)` is somehow nice :)